# Sorting a unordered_map with a std::string as a key in lexicographical order

Tags: c++, string, sorting, c++11, unordered-map

last Week i attended the Catalysts Coding Contest and now i am trying to recreate the Task with more High-Level C++. So I decided to use a `std::unordered_map` consisting of a `std::string` as the key value and a `double` as the mapped type.

The Data looks like this:

```
N0 1.23
N1 2.45
```

and so on.

Now the Problem is that i want to sort this by the string. But it always messes up when trying to sort bigger numbers like

```
N3 1.23
N10 4.56
```

because `1 < 3` and it is comparing it character for character. Now i already tried the `std::sort` function, but i don't really understand how the 3rd Parameter works.

I hope somebody can explain it to me or has a clue how to solve this.

Here is the relevant source code:

```
std::unordered_map <std::string, unsigned int> network;
unsigned int network_power = 1234;
std::unordered_map <std::string, double> network_percent;

for (std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> element : network) {
    double x = ((double)element.second / (double)network_power) * 100;
    x = (int)(x * 100 + 0.5) / 100.0;

    network_percent.insert({element.first, x});
}
```

In the end it should Output each element of `network_percent` in ascending order.

Thanks in advance
Philipp

PS: I already found the other articles on StackOverflow, but don't understand them.

**EDIT:** I am sorry, it was late when i wrote this.

The Code to sort i got until now looks like this:

```
std::sort(network_percent.begin(), network_percent.end());
```

As Peter Becker said i want it to sort it in a non lexicographical order. So when i got Data like:

```
N1 92
N9 309
N2 296
N7 106
N0 218
N3 69
N4 135
N5 68
N6 157
N8 74
N12 576
```

I want it to sort like:

```
N0 218
N1 92
N2 296
N3 69
N4 135
N5 68
N6 157
N7 106
N8 74
N9 309
N12 576
```

At the Moment it messes up when having more than 1 Digit in the key. My Question is: Is there a Function sorting it the way i want?

Comment: The code that you've shown here doesn't seem to attempt to sort anything. Can you post the specific code you used to try to sort the key/value pairs?

Comment: N10 comes before N3 in lexicographical order. What you want is something that's **not** lexicographical order. You can write a comparison function for `std::set` to use, but first you have to describe **exactly** what that function should do. Giving two or three sample values doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Unordered sets and maps doesn't sort anything. They are hashed containers that depends solely on the `operator==` of the key (all keys with same hash will be save in a contiguous region of memory, called bucket). The order given to the keys is unspecified.

Hashed containers are very fast to find if something is inside the container, but are not sorted. If you want sorting, you have to replace the type of `network_percent` for a simple `std::map`.

The `operator<` of `std::string` is implemented following a lexicographical order, so, you don't have to do anything else here to get the intented behaviour.

**NOTE:** Didn't you notice why `unordered_map` is called `unordered`? :)